# Remove Zero Money From Previews Order woocommerce

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have had many orders in the past that the currency is different and has 4 extra zeros. I want to remove these 4 zeros from them and change their currency together.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can update new price using below method -

```
$order_id = 123;

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
    $new_product_price = 30;
    $product_quantity = (int) $item->get_quantity();
    
    $new_line_item_price = $new_product_price * $product_quantity;
    
    $item->set_subtotal( $new_line_item_price ); 
    $item->set_total( $new_line_item_price );

    $item->save(); // Save line item data
}
$order->calculate_totals();
```

Comment: Thank You maulik but this code set new price but my price is different price and items